# Unable to access dynamically changed JavaScript with dynamic HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<style>
*
{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}
textarea
{
    resize: none;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 50%;
}
#output
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 50%;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #222;
}
</style>

<style id="customstyle">
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

function togglehtml()
{
    document.getElementById('inputboxcss').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('inputboxjs').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('inputboxhtml').style.display = "";
}
function togglecss()
{
    document.getElementById('inputboxhtml').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('inputboxjs').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('inputboxcss').style.display = "";
}
function togglejs()
{
    document.getElementById('inputboxcss').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('inputboxhtml').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('inputboxjs').style.display = "";
}

setInterval(function updatehtml()
{
    var x=document.getElementById("inputboxhtml");
    var y=document.getElementById("output");
    y.innerHTML = x.value;
},100);
setInterval(function updatecss()
{
    var x=document.getElementById("inputboxcss");
    var y=document.getElementById("customstyle");
    y.innerHTML = x.value;
},100);
setInterval(function updatejs()
{
    var x=document.getElementById("inputboxjs");
    var y=document.getElementById("customscript");
    y.innerHTML = x.value;
},100);

</script>

<script id="customscript" type="text/javascript">
</script>

<button id="togglehtml" onclick="togglehtml()">HTML</button>
<button id="togglecss" onclick="togglecss()">CSS</button>
<button id="togglejs" onclick="togglejs()">JS</button>
<div id="inputhtml">
    <textarea id="inputboxhtml" onkeypress="updatehtml()"></textarea>
</div>
<div id="inputcss">
    <textarea id="inputboxcss" onkeypress="updatecss()"></textarea>
</div>
<div id="inputjs">
    <textarea id="inputboxjs" onkeypress="updatejs()"></textarea>
</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

[image]

And output window... is attached where
firstblock dynamic html
second block dynamic css
third block dynamic javascript
and fourth block output window... i want just like jsFiddle. but javascript not working and html css are working

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no prior research nor minimal understanding of the problem being solved

Comment: boss.. i got it.. the page need to be reloaded to run javascript code. because it can't compile the code which is in javascript block.. thnx for commenting..

Comment: Thanku boss something like alert() is working but function is not working called by dynamic html

Comment: hey i want <button onclick="alert()">Click me</button> is not working in inputboxhtml but your code is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find your answer here [4 ways to dynamically load external JavaScript(with source)](http://ntt.cc/2008/02/10/4-ways-to-dynamically-load-external-javascriptwith-source.html)

I made a modified version of the add script function:

```
function updatejs()
{
    var x=document.getElementById("inputboxjs");
    addScript("customscript", x.value);
}
function addScript(id, script){
    var headElement = document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD').item(0);
    var oldScriptElement = document.getElementById(id);
    if(oldScriptElement)
        headElement.removeChild(oldScriptElement);
    var scriptElement = document.createElement( "script" );
    scriptElement.type = "text/javascript";
    scriptElement.id = id;
    scriptElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(script));
    headElement.appendChild( scriptElement);
}
```

Another method that is not mentioned in the article would be creating a function object then calling it, giving your custom script its own scope :

```
function updatejs()
{
  var x=document.getElementById("inputboxjs");
  var scriptFnc = new Function(x.value);
  scriptFnc();
}
```

One last thing, giving names to your functions inside `setInterval` call is meaningless.

Recommended reading:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Comment: thanku very much.. i am going to try it and tell you

Comment: Thanku boss something like alert() is working but function is not working called by dynamic html

Comment: What do you mean by function is not working?

Comment: <button onclick="alert()">Click Me</button> is not working in inputboxhtml

Comment: Using the `addScript` method, the function will be called. but you won't see the update as you are updating the html every 100ms. 

Try this: 

function dothisa(){
 alert('clicked');
 document.getElementById('btn').innerHTML = "...";
}

But if you are using the second method `new Function(x.value);`, it will not work as the script will have its own scope and will not be accessible from your button.

Comment: still not working... because dynamically generated html cannot call javascript function

Comment: the javascript (inputboxjs) block is fully enabled and working. but inputboxhtml is not able to call javascript in any way... i tried <script> alert(); </script> in inputboxhtml

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are doing! but here is a working sample http://jsfiddle.net/kt2U9/

Comment: thanku very much its working

Comment: it was not working because of set interval function